# What role does optionType play in a JOptionPane OptionsDialog?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

**Note:** Please pay attention to the fact that this is an Options Dialog here, not a Confirm Dialog. That makes a difference in what I'm asking and how Swing behaves!

I looked at a good code example of an Option Dialog [in action](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/containers/20dialogs/10joptionpane-2.html), but was confused by one thing:

> If you are supplying the dialog with all the options in the `options` parameter, of what use/role/significance is the `optionType` parameter?

According to the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%29) you're options are:

- `DEFAULT_OPTION`
- `YES_NO_OPTION`
- `YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION`; or
- `OK_CANCEL_OPTION`

How do these different options affect the resultant dialog, or does Swing just ignore them?!? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is a valid question that addresses an issue in Swing that is not documented, serving the "content farm" objective of SO.

Comment: You might edit your question to clarify how the relevant [tutorial section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features) is lacking. The accepted answer should probebly be in the tutorial. Voting to keep open for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optionType parameter defines amongst which options the user will have to choose. If you use `YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION`, it will display 3 buttons, one for each option:

- YES
- NO
- CANCEL

[image]

The same goes for all possible optionType values.

Comment: Thanks @Guillame (+1) - but this is not correct. I'm talking about an Options Dialog, where you supply the options as an array of Strings (choices). Please see the code example I linked to. That code example does not produce Yes/No/Cancel buttons like you say.

Comment: @IAmYourFaja My bad, misread your question. It is purely ignored if you provide the `options`